# String manipulation on scriptlet

Tags: java, jsp

I come from a PHP background. I just want to do a simple string replace.

I just want to replace any **question marker** with other character of '-'. in that "Material" string.

If I do

```
<%= Material %>
```

it will simple like write out "BBBB??AC".

I have no another access but just one .jsp file.

Is there another easy way i can do a string replace and print it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this `Material` in your scriptlet is a String, then just do

```
<%= Material.replaceAll("\\?", "-") %>
```

This would basically solve your doubt.

Still, if you can, stop using scriptlets, the reasons are better explained here: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Based on the posted link, the solution would be using EL and JSTL functions:

```
${fn:replace(Material, '?', '-')}
```

---

From your comment, since `Material` is not a String, you could perform a call to `toString` method before applying the replace. In scriptlet:

```
<%= Material.toString().replaceAll("\\?", "-") %>
```

In EL/JSTL you will need a temp variable to handle this:

```
<c:set var="materialString">
     ${Material}
</c:set>
${fn:replace(materialString, '?', '-')}
```

Comment: Hi Luiggi, this is great, but the application just stop render if i use replace method. So i think Material possible is not a String. Is there a way i can parse_string in JSP?

Comment: If `Material` is not a String, probably you would use `Material.toString()`.

Comment: Sweet Lugiggi Thanks so much for your kind help

Comment: Quick one do i need to important any Class in order to do this replace method?

Comment: @bluebill1049 since is a `String`, no. If you're going to use JSTL, you will have to. Please refer to [StackOverflow JSTL wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) for more info about it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30877/discussion-between-bluebill1049-and-luiggi-mendoza)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace string with `<%= Material.replaceAll("\\?","=");%>`

Comment: `String#replaceAll` receives a RegEx as first parameter, and `?` sign in regex is a special character, so it won't do it. Probably you meant `\\?`.

Comment: Forget to add regex... Updated the answer ;